# Yii2: how to use a sum function with a find()?

Tags: sql, yii2, sum

I have a find function in my CarsSearch model that I use in a GridView widget:

```
$query = Cars::find();
```

Now I need to add an SQL SUM function to that find funtion but it doesn't work. SO I tried to show the SQL query and I got this error:

```
$query = Cars::find()->sum('price');
echo $query->createCommand()->sql; // Call to a member function createCommand() on integer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `ActiveQuery::sum()` executes SQL query and already returns it's result.
You don't need to do anything else with it.

```
echo Cars::find()->sum('price');
```

This will output the sum of column price for all rows in table.

If you want to add some conditions or other things you need to do that before calling `sum()` method.

```php
echo Cars::find()->where(['category' => 'SUV'])->sum('price')
```

This will output sum of price for all cars with "SUV" as their category.

If you need to use sql `SUM()` function for one column in query selecting more columns you can't use `ActiveQuery::sum()` method. Instead you can use `select()` or `addSelect()` method to tell the query what columns you want to select.

```php
$query = Cars::find()
    ->select([
        'sumPrices' => 'SUM(price)',
        'countCars' => 'COUNT(*)'
    ]);
```

See the [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#select()-detail) for more info.